# Is it possible to change OData query, via user input, in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerquery, powerbi-datasource

I need to create something, which is being used a few times a year. 
I need to get the latest rows since the report was used last.

My OData endpoint allows me to modify a timespan, to limit the number of rows I get (if I get all of them, I will get 12+ million rows).

The users aren't going to be knowing anything about Power BI, and I want to avoid them having the change the query manually. What I basically want is a slicer, allowing them to input a date, which will then be parsed into the query, instead of the original value, and then update the table with the new query.

An example of a filter on the OData query, selecting all files from 2020, is this:

```
Files?$filter=Created%20ge%20datetime%272020-01-01T00:00:00%2b01:00%27&$select=ID,......"
```

If it is possible, then how would I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Slicers can't change queries, except in DirectQuery models.  And OData isn't a DirectQuery source.  You can build up a dynamic query on refresh, or you can have your users refresh using PowerBI and change a Parameter.